# cloning a table and adding new columns with input text fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="table sortable" id="table_rolecart">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" class="sorting">
                    remove
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <span class="column-sort">
                      <a class="sort-up" title="Sort up" href="#"></a>
                      <a class="sort-down" title="Sort down" href="#"></a>
                    </span>
                  Role Name
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <span class="column-sort">
                      <a class="sort-up" title="Sort up" href="#"></a>
                      <a class="sort-down" title="Sort down" href="#"></a>
                    </span>
            Role Description
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <tr class="odd">
                  <td><a href="#"><img src="/gra/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png" class="move-row" alt="Remove"></a></td>
                    <td><span style="color: black;">sharepoint_readonly</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color: black;">Role with read-only access to Sharepoint Document Repository</span></td>
                </tr><tr class="even">
                  <td><a href="#"><img src="/gra/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png" class="move-row" alt="Remove"></a></td>
                    <td><span style="color: black;">agile_unix_box</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color: black;">Role with read/write access to Agile repository Unix Server</span></td>
                </tr></tbody>

            </table>
```

I need to copy this table to another table on the next page onclick of 'next' button and also add 2 new columns to every row which have input type = text and one has a datepicker associated with it. The resulting table on the new page is inside a form and I need to save it on click of the 'submit' on that page
How do I clone the data on this table and add the required columns to it?
Regards,
Priyank

Comment: $( "#id_of_table_clone" ).html( $( "#table_rolecart" ).html() ); this will copy the internal html, I'll leave it up to you to add new columns